# neo4django admin interface not working?

Tags: neo4django

I followed the instructions in the [neo4django:admin docs](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/blob/master/docs/admin.rst), also set up the neo4django:auth according to the [instructions](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/blob/master/docs/auth.rst).

However, after logging in I get

"You don't have permission to edit anything."

I want to edit the data defined in my `lit` app. My `lit/admin.py` looks like:

```
from neo4django import admin
from lit.models import Literature

admin.site.register(Literature)
```

...if that matters.

Any ideas what I got wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Any chance you could share the `MIDDLEWARE` and `INSTALLED_APPS` parts of your settings.py? I've run into this too- trying to follow my own instructions, nonetheless!

EDIT:

Here's a copy of part of my settings.py, urls.py and admin.py for a toy social networking app I'm putting together as a demo. These work fine with the latest neo4django, against Neo4j 1.9.

social_network/settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'neo4django.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'neo4django.admin',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'friends', # the django app
)
```

social_network/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from neo4django import admin

admin.autodiscover()

from friends.views import (...)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Finally, friends/admin.py looks like

```
from neo4django import admin
from .models import Person

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```